# Is $P(X|A,B)=\frac{P(A|X)P(B|X)P(X)}{P(A)P(B)}$ when $A$ and $B$ are conditionally indepdent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I am trying to evaluate $P(X|A,B)$ given that $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $X$. I know that this can be expressed as,

$$P(X|A,B)=\frac{P(A,B,X)}{P(A,B)}$$

Using the conditional independence of $A$ and $B$ given $X$ this is,
$$\frac{P(A|B,X)P(B,X)}{P(A)P(B)}=\frac{P(A|X)P(B,X)}{P(A)P(B)}$$
Using the chain rule this is
$$\frac{P(A|X)P(B|X)P(X)}{P(A)P(B)}$$

Is this correct? Does this hold with conditional independence of $A$ and $B$ given $X$, or does it also require independence alone of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: You split $P(A, B) = P(A)P(B)$ -- that is independence of $A, B$, not conditional independence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save some steps using Bayes' formula:
$$
P(X \mid A, B) = \frac{P(A, B \mid X)P(X)}{P(A, B)}
$$
Using the conditional independence, this is
$$
\frac{P(A \mid X) P(B \mid X) P(X)}{P(A, B)}
$$
But as has been pointed out, you cannot factor the denominator without assuming independence of $A$ and $B$

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote your answer but due to my low reputation the system does not permit me.

Answer (score 0):

Almost correct:
$$P(X|A,B) = \frac{P(A|X)P(B|X)P(X)}{P(A,B)}$$

You know that A and B are conditionally independent given X but not that A and B are independent (that cannot be assumed).

Comment: Thanks! I would upvote your answer but due to my low reputation the system does not permit me.